How to fix the error stripe: No stripe-signature header value was provided
In strapi I am trying to get the payment events from stripe, I made a webhook inside a collection called "Order", it seems that the webhook works because it does manage to get the events since it does print the information with a console.log but I always get the following error: No stripe-signature header value was provided.
I already have my account created and configured, and Stripe accepts payments without needing the webhook. However, I want to implement the webhook, so I’m using the terminal with Stripe CLI to run tests locally.
First, I run the following command:

stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:1337/api/orders/stripe-webhook

This generates a key and displays the message:

“Ready! You are using Stripe API Version [2024-11-20]. Your webhook signing secret is whsec_69b...”.

I set this key (whsec_69b...) in my environment variable STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET.
Then, I use the following command to simulate an event (also known as a trigger):
stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded.
The webhook receives the event correctly, but when validating the webhook, I get an error that I can’t seem to resolve.
async handleWebhook(ctx) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(ctx.request.body);
        const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
        const signature = ctx.request.headers['stripe-signature']

        console.log(body);
        console.log(signature);
        console.log(endpointSecret);
        
        

        try {
            // Asegúrate de pasar el cuerpo como Buffer o String crudo
            const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, signature, endpointSecret);

            // Procesar el evento
            if (event.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
                const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
                console.log('Pago exitoso:', paymentIntent);
            }

            // Responde con 200 OK
            ctx.status = 200;
            ctx.body = 'Webhook recibido correctamente';
        } catch (err) {
            // Error en la verificación de la firma
            console.error('Error al procesar el webhook:', err.message);
            ctx.status = 400;
            ctx.body = `Error del webhook: ${err.message}`;
        }

    },

this is the route/order.js
'use strict';

/**
 * order router
 */
module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/orders', // Ruta para crear pedidos
      handler: 'order.create',
      config: {
        policies: [],
      },
    },
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      path: '/orders/:id', // Ruta para actualizar pedidos
      handler: 'order.update', // Usa el controlador predeterminado para actualizar
      config: {
        policies: [], // Puedes agregar políticas de autorización aquí
      },
    },
    {
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/orders/:id/update-stripe', // Ruta personalizada para actualizar stripeId
      handler: 'order.updateStripeId', // Necesitas definir este controlador
      config: {
        policies: [], // Agrega restricciones si es necesario
      },
    },
    {
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/orders/stripe-webhook',
      handler: 'order.handleWebhook',
      config: {
        auth: false,
       
      },
    },
  ],
};








I have tried to put this code like this: 
> ​​const body = ctx.request.body
 but it does not solve it


You might need to use the express.raw middleware (i.e., express.raw({type: 'application/json'}) to make sure that the body data is raw. You can find some example code in the webhook builder, and refer to this doc for more possible solutions for webhook signature verification error.
